# Trying to add HOVER to an ID that is created on the fly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61152639/background-images-of-div-inside-table-cells-not-loading-on-the-fly) a few moments ago.

In the question I was trying to create a table at run time. That is working perfectly now with the help of Omri Attiya who answer the question.

I have slightly modified his solution to this one that is also working perfectly.

```
var celulaCSS = `
{
  background-image: url('thumbnails/thumbnailXXX.jpg');
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  width:300px; 
  height:169px;
  transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
  margin: 0 auto;
}`;

function createDiv(number) {
  var numString = number.toString(10);
  const type = 'text/css';

  var css = "#thumbnailXXX".concat(celulaCSS);
  css = css.replace(/XXX/g, numString);

  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'thumbnailXXX'.replace(/XXX/g, numString);
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = type;
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  document.head.appendChild(style);
  return div;
}
```

`createDiv(number)` will create a css `id`s like `#thumbnailX`, where X is the number passed to the function, create a `div`, apply that `id` to the new div and return that.

What I am trying to do now is to add a `hover` property to that id, by creating a new style called `#thumbnailX:hover {transform: scale(1.5);}` and adding that to the body styles.

So, I modified the code to

```
var celulaCSS = `
{
  background-image: url('thumbnails/thumbnailXXX.jpg');
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  width:300px; 
  height:169px;
  transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
  margin: 0 auto;
}`;

var celulaZOOM = `
{
    transform: scale(1.5); 
}`;


function createDiv(number) {
  var numString = number.toString(10);
  const type = 'text/css';

  var css = "#thumbnailXXX".concat(celulaCSS);
  css = css.replace(/XXX/g, numString);

  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'thumbnailXXX'.replace(/XXX/g, numString);
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = type;
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  document.head.appendChild(style);

  // THIS IS NOT WORKING
  var cssZoom = "#thumbnailXXX:hover".concat(celulaZOOM);
  cssZoom = cssZoom.replace(/XXX/g, numString);
  var styleZoom = document.createElement('style');
  styleZoom = type;
  styleZoom.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cssZoom));
  document.head.appendChild(styleZoom);
  return div;
}
```

but the last part of `createDiv` is not working. No error on console.

Comment: Why don't you use a proper CSS file and classes? They can be there all day long before creating the table dynamically.

Comment: There is no way to do that because I don't know how many cells the table will have and each cell contains a div with a specific background. Omri Attiya pointed my error. It's now working. Thanks.

Comment: There is surely a way to do this. You create your class beforehand but assign the class dynamically. What you are doing here is creating the CSS rules on the fly. You should encapsule these css rules in a class and then it's simply a matter of doing an if else statement in your table function. If this then class A else class B. Simple, and that's how its done since ancient times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your code is working. You just wrote `styleZoom = type` instead of `styleZoom.type = type` so you basically set `styleZoom` to a text and override the element.

Once again I think it's better to just give all elements a class, and add to the css:

```
.myClass:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH, you are right. Just missed that. THANKS AGAIN.